# How to sort data in other language characters in angular material table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

For example in turkish we have some special characters like 'ç ,ğ, ö' etc. And I want to be able to sort with them. Is it possible? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort order is determined doing a lexicographical sort by comparing the Unicode.
This article offers you two solution for your problem: [check it out](http://www.janholinka.net/Blog/Article/8)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the collation changes the result.
I faced the same problem and I solved it like this:

```js
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'orderBy'
    })
    export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform(array: any, field: string, isAscending: boolean): any[] {
        if (isAscending) {
          array.sort((a: any, b: any) =>
            a[field].localeCompare(b[field], 'tr'));

          return array;
        } else {
          array.sort((a: any, b: any) =>
            b[field].localeCompare(a[field], 'tr'));

          return array;
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is the usage:

```html
    <div class="col-lg-6" *ngFor="let entity of entities$ | orderBy: 'name' : true">
```

I hope this solution works for you.